# Select and delete multiple rows from indexed column

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to clean my data, I have over than 500K rows. I want to select all the columns that have "H" AND "F", go through each row and delete the entire row if either "H" or "F" have a value that is greater than 2000 or less than -150.
I have written a code that deletes the rows with this condition from all the columns, but I want to specify the columns "H" AND "F".

I have included my code and a sample of the data.

Thank you

```
def load_csv(path, d_keyls):
    f = open(path, 'r')
    data = {}
    data["names"] = f.readline().replace('\n', '').split(',')
    indexes = [data["names"].index(el) for el in data["names"] if el[0] in d_keyls]

    for line in f:
        row = line.replace('\n', '').split(',')
        PartId = row[-2]
        T = row[-1]
        app_row = row[:-2]
        app_row1 = [float(num) if num != "" else 0 for num in app_row ]
        
        key_to_del = False

        for num in app_row:
            if num > 400 or num < -150:
                key_to_del = True

        if key_to_del:
            pass
        else:
            if T in data:
                if PartId in data[T]:
                    data[T][PartId].append(app_row)
                else:
                    data[T][PartId] = [app_row]
            else:
                data[T] = {PartId: [app_row]}


    for key in data:
        if key != "names":
            #Converting native Python 2d list to numpy.array
            for pid in data[key]:
                data[key][pid] = np.array(data[key][pid], dtype='float_')
    f.close()
    return data

input_file = 'init.csv'
export_file = 'Query_celn.csv'

d_keyls = ["H","F"]

data = load_csv(input_file, d_keyls)
```

[image]

Comment: You'll probably see great benefit from the Pandas library, which is practically a wrapper which makes numpy structures easier to work with and provides features such as loading CSVs and filtering by some criteria!

Comment: to add on @ti7 pandas "is basically a wrapper on numpy" on 2-d tables! if you want more dimensions, pandas may or may not suit you

Answer (score 1):

Solved instead for those lines

```
for num in app_row:
    if num > 400 or num < -150:
```

I replaced it to:

```
for i in indexes:
    if app_row[i]> 400 or app_row[i]< -150:
```

Thanks to @David Erickson