# accessing each element of a list according to given list of indexes TypeError

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I want to access each element of the area according to given list of indexes for loop, but I am getting a TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable.

Is there a way I can do that ?

really appreciated

```
index=[0, 1, 5, 6, 10, 11]
area=[78.0, 125.0, 203.0, 266.0, 344.0, 141.0, 46.0, 187.0, 245.0, 265.0, 78.0, 203.0]
key_to_del = False

for x in index:    
    for j in area:
        if float(j[x]) >150:
            print(j[x])
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Evidently you know that `x` will take on successive values of `index`.  Isn't `j` do the same?  If so what's the purpose of `j[x]`?

Comment: I am trying to solve this problem :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64444377/select-and-delete-multiple-rows-from-indexed-column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to loop through area with `j`, because you are looping through the index and calling certain values of area based on index, so you can just use:

```
index=[0, 1, 5, 6, 10, 11]
area=[78.0, 125.0, 203.0, 266.0, 344.0, 141.0, 46.0, 187.0, 245.0, 265.0, 78.0, 203.0]
key_to_del = False

for x in index:
    if area[x] >150:
        print(area[x])

203.0
```

Out of the specified values in the index, the final index value `11` is the only one that returns a number above 150, which is `203` which is index of `11` or position 12.

Comment: I can't express my gratitude enough, you solve this problem for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64444377/select-and-delete-multiple-rows-from-indexed-column